# Component level server side data fetching

Tags: reactjs, next.js, environment-variables, server-side-rendering

.env.local has 2 values username and password which is secret and must not be visible to the user in the browser. I should use this data and fetch the token. The problem is env is only accessible in server and I must do server side api call only. Now the token should be accessible all over the app so I need to fetch it somewhere like _app.js but here its not supported. I found out 2 solutions.

1. Client side fetch the data and use it (env variables not accessible)
2. Server side fetch the data in all pages (cant do SSR in components)

Comment: Could you clarify what the question is? Are you asking which of the two solutions should you go with?

Comment: I have issues with both the solutions, my question is "Where should I do server side API call and store data which will be accessible in all pages and components"

Comment: Have a look at the [custom `_app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) and its `App.getInitialProps`.

Comment: Does it not make my whole app server side rendered?

Comment: Not necessarily, it depends what data fetching methods (`getStaticProps`/`getServerSideProps`/none) you use in each page.

Comment: Just tried, its making all my pages server side rendered. Even if I am not using any data fetching methods.

Comment: What do you mean by _"all my pages server side rendered"_? By default, Next.js pre-generates all pages on the server. What data fetching method do you use in your pages?

Comment: I have getserversideprops in one page and all other pages are client side data fetching. But as  soon as I added getinitialprops in _app.js all pages have lambda (SSR).

Comment: Right, I see what you mean. That's indeed caused by the `_app`'s `getInitialProps`. If you don't want that behaviour, then you have to fetch the data on each page instead. You can't really achieve what you want and not have everything server-side rendered.